# ECS service getting timeout while creating

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs

I am trying to create a new ECS EC2 service.

My cloudformation is getting timeout while creating the service.

I have checked all roles,docker images are fine.

How to debugg this issue ?

Is anything i can login in ECS EC2 and check ?

Answer (score 2):

> Is anything i can login in ECS EC2 and check ?

Yes, you can. Specifically, you can go to your ECS service and check its `Events` tab:

[image]

Also in the `Tasks`, you can check `Stopped` tasks. Go to the stopped task if any and you can expand its details. Often there will be some extra info while it was stopped.

[image]

Comment: There is nothing in my events tab.

Comment: @AWS_Beginner So the service may not be even launched and failure occurs earlier.

Comment: yes maybe.Cloudformation takes long time to create service and then it fails saying maximum attempts reached.Any pointers how can i debug this?

Comment: @AWS_Beginner Where are you deploying it? If its a private subnet in a custom VPC, does it have internet connectivity?

Comment: Do you mean the EC2 where this container will run should have internet connectivity?

Comment: @AWS_Beginner Yes. So it does not have it ?

Comment: Yes it check SG and subnet.It looks like connectivity is there.But when i login in EC2 i can see its not fetching correct image but in TD i have given correct repo and image name.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the health checks on the ELB is failing due to them not getting HTTP 200 from the checks that you have configured (or not configured in which case they must get a HTTP 200 from "GET /").

Comment: How can can verify this ? Is there anything i can loggin in EC2 and check?

Comment: Yes, go to EC2->Elastic Load Balancer->Target Groups.
You should have one Target Group per ECS service.
You can configure the path that the health check uses for each Target Group.
You can see if the health checks have failed or succeeded.